# Chaining api calls in RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java

I have a service for fetching movies:

```
Single<List<Movie>> fetchAll();
```

and a service for fetching trailers for each movie:

```
Single<List<Video>> fetchByMovieId(@Path("movie_id") long movieId);
```

After fetching all movies I'd like to also fetch their trailers and return a list of objects that composes of a movie and all of it's trailers. What is a proper way to achieve this using RxJava?

Answer (score 3):

ps: You should avoid make lot of requests. Try to do this on demand.

```
yourClient.fetchAll()
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .toObservable()
          .flatMapIterable(movies -> movies)
          .flatMap(movie -> yourClient.fetchByMovieId(movie.getId()))
          .toList()
          .subscribe()...
```

Comment: I tried this approach but it results in a `Single<List<Videos>>` where I'd expect something more like: `Single<List<Pair<Movie, List<Videos>>>`